# How to override parent datacontext in child panel

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I want to override parent (grid) datacontext  in one of the child panel (stackpanel), 
such that any update in any of the stackpanel, xml file will get updated accordingly.

Initially I had  XPath="/Data/MB" attribute in XmlDataProvider. So with this binding in only textbox 5 and 6 was successful.

Finally what I did is given below. This works fine.

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.DataContext> 
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="Credentials" Source="Credentials.xml"/> 
    </Grid.DataContext> 
    <StackPanel> 
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox5" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=/Credentials/MessageBroker/Hostname}" /> 
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox6" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=/Credentials/MessageBroker/Port}"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
    <StackPanel> 
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox9" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=/Credentials/Database/Server}" /> 
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox10" Width="188" Text="{Binding XPath=/Credentials/Database/Password}"/> 
    </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

Here is Credentials.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Credentials> 
<MB> 
  <Hostname>145.111.227.222</Hostname> 
  <Port>5672</Port> 
  <UserName>Admin</UserName> 
  <Password>Admin</Password> 
</MB> 
<Database> 
  <Server>145.111.227.234</Server> 
  <UserID>Administrator</UserID> 
  <Password>password</Password> 
</Database>
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Please let me know.

Comment: "This works fine." "Is there any better way to do it?" o_O

Comment: if it's not broken don't fix it.

Comment: I have written this code. I wanted a better solution, if there is. Because, if the xml file were <database><server><user><user1>Administrator</user1></user></server></database> , my binding code will change to Text="{Binding XPath=/Credentials/database/server/user/user1}". I want to avoid this.